# HTML - MDL Checkbox/Toggle Centering

Tags: html, css

I have tried to use both of these components in my html document but neither of them will center. With the checkbox the text gets centered but the icon will remain to the left of the page.

```html
<label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="checkbox-1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" class="mdl-checkbox__input" checked>
  <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Checkbox</span>
</label>

<label class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="switch-1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="switch-1" class="mdl-switch__input" checked>
  <span class="mdl-switch__label"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: I have tried <center></center> and also CSS to center them but neither work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display:block` for label and center align labels.

```css
label
{
  text-align:center;
}
.mdl-checkbox, .mdl-switch{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="checkbox-1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" class="mdl-checkbox__input" checked>
  <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Checkbox</span>
</label>

<label class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="switch-1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="switch-1" class="mdl-switch__input" checked>
  <span class="mdl-switch__label">Checkbox 2</span>
</label>
```

Comment: [link](http://prntscr.com/goi0kj) The the icons seems to go to the left of the page.

Comment: You need to check other styles as well, I guess mdl uses psuedo elements to create toggle with label, so you need to change for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I used flex on the label to center the items inside. It also aligns the content vertically so your input is inline with your label.

```css
.mdl-checkbox, .mdl-switch{
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="checkbox-1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" class="mdl-checkbox__input" checked>
  <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Checkbox</span>
</label>

<label class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="switch-1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="switch-1" class="mdl-switch__input" checked>
  <span class="mdl-switch__label">Checkbox 2</span>
</label>
```